# I've an error with SVG and google fonts "Monoton"

Tags: css, svg, google-font-api, google-fonts

Hy guys,
When I open the svg file in a browser, It gives me an "error on line 4 at column 76: EntityRef: expecting ';' "
this is the svg code:

```css
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="96.75" height="33" viewBox="0 0 387 132">
  <defs>
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Monoton&display=swap');
      .cls-1 {
        font-size: 150px;
        fill: #888;
        font-family: Monoton;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <text id="DAG" class="cls-1" x="-7.001" y="126.575">DAG</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove: `&display=swap` (line 4 at column 76)

```css
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="96.75" height="33" viewBox="0 0 387 132">
  <defs>
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Monoton');
      .cls-1 {
        font-size: 150px;
        fill: #888;
        font-family: Monoton;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <text id="DAG" class="cls-1" x="-7.001" y="126.575">DAG</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, also I have to put the quotation marks in "Monoton"

Comment: Is not necessarily